# Infinate While Loop. Stalling the program

Tags: java, while-loop, logic, infinite-loop

So, I am working on a large project for programming 1. I cannot figure out how to stop the infinite while loop with any of the other ways provided on the web site. Here is all the methods that involve making the move of the player:

```
public boolean movement(Move m, int moved){
        int rowM, colM, row, col;
        Player p = m.getPlayer();
        if (moved == 0 || moved == 1 || moved == 7)
            rowM = -1;
        if (moved == 2 || moved == 6)
            rowM = 0;
        if (moved == 3 || moved == 4 || moved == 5)
            rowM = 1;
        else
            rowM = 0;
        if (moved == 5 || moved == 6 || moved == 7)
            colM = -1;
        if (moved == 0 || moved == 4)
            colM = 0;
        if (moved == 1 || moved == 2 || moved == 3)
            colM = 1;
        else
            colM = 0;
        row = rowM + m.getRow();
        col = colM + m.getColumn();
        if (!onBoard(row, col) || !getPiece(row, col).opposite(p.getPiece()))
            return false;
        while ((onBoard(row,col))&&(getPiece(row,col).opposite(p.getPiece()))){
            row += rowM;
            col += colM;
        }
        if (onBoard(row, col) && getPiece(row, col).opposite(p.getPiece()))
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    private void change(Move m, int moved){
        int rowM, colM, row, col;
        Player p = m.getPlayer();
        if (moved == 0 || moved == 1 || moved == 7)
            rowM = -1;
        if (moved == 2 || moved == 6)
            rowM = 0;
        if (moved == 3 || moved == 4 || moved == 5)
            rowM = 1;
        else
            rowM = 0;
        if (moved == 5 || moved == 6 || moved == 7)
            colM = -1;
        if (moved == 0 || moved == 4)
            colM = 0;
        if (moved == 1 || moved == 2 || moved == 3)
            colM = 1;
        else
            colM = 0;
        row = rowM + m.getRow();
        col = colM + m.getColumn();
        while (getPiece(row, col).opposite(p.getPiece())){
            setPiece(p.getPiece(), row, col);
            row += rowM;
            col += colM;
        }
    }
    public void makeMove(Move move){
        Player p = move.getPlayer();
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            if (movement(move, c))
                change(move, c);
        }
        setPiece(p.getPiece(), move.getRow(), move.getColumn());
    }
    public int handleTurn(Display display){
        Move m = display.getMove(this.current);

        if (!moveLegal(m)){
            display. displayMessage("Illegal Move!");
            return 1;
        }
        makeMove(m);
        Player p = getNextPlayer();
        if (p == current)
            display.displayMessage("Skipped! " + other.getName().toString()); 
        if (gameOver())
            return -1;
        else {
            other = current;
            current = p;
        }
        display.displayStatus(current, "Your Move!");
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: What infinite loop where? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: That is how I found it. It is is the movement method.

Comment: check the methods onBoard(row, col) and getPiece what do these do?

Answer (score 1):

I would need more of your source code to give you a precise answer. However, I believe I can help you with some observations.

- The program will always enter an infinite loop if the method
  parameter `moved` is outside the range `0` through `7`.
- In the movement method, the final `if` condition can never evaluate
  to `true`, because the same condition was required to evaluate to
  `false` before the loop could exit.

Based on these observations, I suggest you try this version of the movement method:

```
public boolean movement(Move m, int moved)
{
    int rowM, colM, row, col;
    Player p = m.getPlayer();
    if (moved == 0 || moved == 1 || moved == 7)
        rowM = -1;
    else if (moved == 3 || moved == 4 || moved == 5)
        rowM = 1;
    else // moved == 2 || moved == 6
        rowM = 0;
    if (moved == 5 || moved == 6 || moved == 7)
        colM = -1;
    else if (moved == 1 || moved == 2 || moved == 3)
        colM = 1;
    else // moved == 0 || moved == 4
        colM = 0;
    row = rowM + m.getRow();
    col = colM + m.getColumn();
    return onBoard(row, col) && getPiece(row, col).opposite(p.getPiece());
}
```